# Getting product list in a magento2 module

Tags: php, magento, magento2

I am trying to fetch all product list into my module inside magento2 application, but not able to figure out how.

My Block code:

```
class Crud extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
{
    protected $objectManager;
    public function __construct(Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory $resultPageFactory,
        \Magento\Framework\ObjectManagerInterface $objectManager,
        \Magento\Framework\App\State $appState
    )
    {
        $this->objectManager = $objectManager;
      //  $appState->setAreaCode('frontend');
        parent::__construct($context);
    }

    function _prepareLayout(){}

    function getCrudName(){
        return "Products for holmes chat client";
    }

    function getProductList(){
     //   $objectMan= new \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager;
        $objectMan= $this->$objectManager;
        $repo = $objectMan->get('Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductRepository');
        $search_criteria = $objectMan->create(
            'Magento\Framework\Api\SearchCriteriaInterface'
        );
        $result = $repo->getList($search_criteria);
      //  $list = $repo->getList();
      $products = $result->getItems();
        return $products;
        // return 'some';
    }

    function getProducts(){
        $objectMan = new Holmes\ChatClient\Api\ProductFetcher;
    }
}
```

My template code:

```
<h2>This is a crud html</h2>
<h3>

    <?php
        echo $block->getCrudName();
    ?>
</h3>
<ul>
    <?php
       echo $block->getProductList();
    ?>
</ul>
```

My browser is throwing an error as:

```
3 exception(s):
Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException): Invalid block type: Holmes\ChatClient\Block\Crud
Exception #1 (ReflectionException): Class Holmes\ChatClient\Block\Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context does not exist
Exception #2 (ReflectionException): Class Holmes\ChatClient\Block\Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context does not exist
```

I am new to magento and the block code is working if I remove the constructor and remove the method `getProductList()` from code. And can I write code inside a magento Block.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot declaring the visibility of the functions. This might solve your problem. If it doesn't, please include your layout xml file, the namespace at the top of your file and your controller.

Change:

`function getProducts(){` to `public function getProducts() {`

`function _prepareLayout(){}` to `protected function _prepareLayout(){}`

`function getCrudName(){` to `public function getCrudName(){`

`function getProductList(){` to `public function getProductList(){`.

Comment: I tried changing the visibilities. But I think the problem is not there. The block is working fine for other methods like `getCrudName()` . The view is properly rendered if `getProductList()` is not called. I think there is problem with the logic or implementation to fetch product list

Comment: I found another mistake: `$objectMan= $objectManager;` should be `$objectMan = $this->objectManager;` Does that solve anything? Also please note that if the function works, the returned object will be huge.

Comment: No, I still get an exception as
`3 exception(s):
Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException): Invalid block type: Holmes\ChatClient\Block\Crud
Exception #1 (ReflectionException): Class Holmes\ChatClient\Block\Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context does not exist
Exception #2 (ReflectionException): Class Holmes\ChatClient\Block\Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context does not exist`

Comment: `(Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context,` you should change it to `(\Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context,` and then run `php bin/magento setup:di:compile && chmod -R 777 var` in your Magento root folder. It's strange that it works if you don't call `getProductList()`.